# Using SharePoint 2007& SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-page

We are using SharePoint 2007 for our Intranet and I am using SharePoint Designer 2007 to work on my 'issue.' Here is the situation, I created a site and would like to have 3 rows and 3 columns of web parts. The problem I having is getting them to line up in rows and columns. I would like to have it look like a 'Tic, Tac, Toe' site. I'm creating clickable graphics for the site. I can send screen shots if needed.
Hope someone can help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SharePoint 2007 your simplest solution would be to create a custom Page Layout.  See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-a-publishing-page-layout-HA010174129.aspx for details on how to do so.

You could create a table layout (for simplicity) that layouts of the sections you want and then put a web part zone in each table cell.